# Responsive width with min-height and overflow

Tags: html, css

Ok, I can't seem to figure out how to do this for the life of me...

I have a layout that is 100% responsive. But I am comparing some products side by side on a specific page. So I have the content responsive but can only get so small. So I want my center container to be able to fit normally which it does but set a min-width of 767px. Once it hits this size the rest of the layout should still stay responsive and shrink with the browser but the content should stay at 767px and its container should have a scroll bar. All the rest of the site needs to stay with size of browser but just this container should have a slidebar and not shrink smaller than 767px. Does anyone have any idea how this could be done??

Comment: show some code....

Comment: Definitely show some...

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: Tell if I'm right. You've 3 div: A, B and C (and maybe others); A contains B and C; C is the one with min-width:767px; you want that when the width of A is <767px, A has a scrollbar, so that you can see all B.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the css media queries to perform the responsive options as same as what you need.